# ERROR: module or package not found: (missing __init__.py?) - PyCharm - Python

Tags: python, testing, automation, pycharm

I'm trying to perform som automated tests on PyCharm but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: module or package not found: (missing __init__.py?)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRGmZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9wmQ.png)

Someone know what could be?

I'm trying to performe automated tests

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just creating a `__init__.py` file? These files are usually empty anyway.